# Registration form on an iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have an application developed using iOS5.  I have used the storyboard to design the whole screens.  The problem I am facing right now is that, when the user runs the application for the very first time, I have to show a view for the user to register. I have no clue on earth on how to do it. I have created the registration forms on the storyboard itself.

Can someone put some light on this issue please?

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and also check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

Set a value after the user starts the application:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"registered"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and then check with this:

```
NSNumber *numb=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"registered"];
    if ([numb isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        NSLog(@"registered");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"not registered");
    }
```

Comment: Whether the current user is registered or not can be known from my local database. 

That solves half of my problem. But how can call a particular view from the same storyboard if the user is not registered?

Comment: Let us assume that I have the main view as the first view on the storyboard.  I have another view for registeration. When the application starts, if the user is not registered, then I need to show the registration view instead of the default main view. And once the registration is over, I need to show the main view.

Comment: You can use the same code anywhere, if the user is not registered call your particular view in the `else` block.

Comment: ...so you have to run the first snippet if you know the user is registered, then use the second snippet to call your view if the user is not registered in the else block.

Comment: I guess you guys got me wrong.  I have a single storyboard with a number of scenes in it.  The start scene is named 'Main'. When the user runs for the very first time, I need to check whether the user is registered or not.  If the user is not registered, then I need to show a scene called 'Registration'.  I able to check whether the user is registered or not.  The issue I am facing is that I am not sure how I can run the 'Registration' scene instead of the Main Scene.  Hope my question is clear.